# 1048, "Column 'productos_id' cannot be null"

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Tengo el siguiente código que arroja el error:
1048, "Column 'productos_id' cannot be null"
Si alguien me puede ayudar en esto, estaré enormemente agradecido porque soy un novato en el tema.

my model:

```
class ProductoOrden(models.Model):
producto = models.IntegerField()
cantidad_producto = models.IntegerField()
total_productos = models.IntegerField()

class OrdenDeCompra(models.Model):
productos = models.ForeignKey('ordenescompra.ProductoOrden', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="productos")
usuario = models.IntegerField()
gran_total = models.IntegerField()
status = models.IntegerField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de creacion')
```

view:

```
class OrdenDeCompra(APIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def get(self,request):
    queryset = OrdenDeCompraModel.objects.all()
    serializer = OrdenDeCompraSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self,request):
    serializer = OrdenDeCompraSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer:

```
class OrdenDeCompraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = OrdenDeCompra
    fields = ['id','productos','usuario','gran_total','status']
    read_only_fields = ('productos',)

class ProductoOrdenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
productos = OrdenDeCompraSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = ProductoOrden
    fields = ['id','producto','cantidad_producto','total_productos','productos']

def create(self, validated_data):
    productos_data = validated_data.pop('productos')
    productoorden = ProductoOrden.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for producto_data in productos_data:
        OrdenDeCompra.objects.create(productoorden=productoorden, **producto_data)

    return productoorden
```

tome de ayuda la documentacion de https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/, pero no he tenido éxito en ejecutar con postman

Necesito hacer un post como este:

```
{
"usuario": 14,
"gran_total": 177000,
"status": 1,
"productos":[
    {
        "producto":12,
        "cantidad_producto":1,
        "total_productos":177000
    }
    ]
```

}

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta publicación en el postman?
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta por favor pues estás en SO en español

Comment: En esta línea "def post(self)", tu código espera "def post(self, request)".

Comment: disculpen es q casi todas las dudas las he buscado en ingles, ya agregue en si el request en la view pero ps ahora me aparece otra incognita y ps no he podido solucionarlo con respecto a modelos anidados. gracias